# GWT and JSInterop namespace

Tags: javascript, java, gwt

I've got some native JS test code here (mydialog.js)

```
var MyDialog = {

    foo : function()
    {
        console.log("foo");
    }
};
```

I'm injecting using the following code using GWT:

```
ScriptInjector.fromUrl("mydialog.js").setCallback(new Callback<Void, Exception>()
{
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Exception reason)
    {
        Window.alert("Dialog Injection Failed!" + reason);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void result) {}

    }).inject();
}
```

Then, I'm trying to set up a JSInterop class here:

```
@JsType(isNative=true, namespace=JsPackage.GLOBAL, name="MyDialog")
public class MyDialog
{            
    public static native void foo();
}
```

The problem, is that the namesoace JsPackage.GLOBAL isn't accurate. The injected code doesn't live under the global namespace, but rather the one generated by GWT and presumably inside the GWT iframe I believe. What is the namespace I need?

In other words, what should this be:

```
...namespace=???...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JsInterop assumes that the code it is reasoning about lives in the main window - this isn't the difference of a namespace, but a different global context that it runs under (with different Object, Array types, etc). In Java terms you might consider this not just "wrong package", but "wrong classloader", though in a way that you can't correct very nicely.

Instead, direct the ScriptInjector to put your created JS into the main page, and you can interact with it directly with `setWindow`:

```
ScriptInjector.fromUrl(...)
    .setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW)
    .setCallback(...);
```

Alternatively, you can use the "magic" string of `"<window>"`, which will mean "don't provide any namespace at all". This isn't an official part of JsInterop (the constant isn't declared in the jsinterop annotations themselves), but at least presently is a way you can work around this.

Comment: Okay, figured as much it worked along those lines. Thanks!